# How to overcome "Insufficient previliges" on accessing child object while its parent have public read only access?

Tags: administration, sharing, owd, admin, record-access-level

In my org, Account object have OWD as public read only.
And I have a custom object C1 which is a child of Account (Master-Detail Relationship).

If a new record is created for C1, it gets saved at the Account which is in the top of Account Hierarchy.

The problem is, I have sharing rules on Account based on the Field 'Sales Region'.

> The user in one region has only Read access on the records in another region.

So, if I have a record for Custom object C1, whose Parent is A1 (Account) which is in one region e.g. Asia, while A1's parent A2's sales region is another e.g Europe. If I try to create an attachment or Notes for a record of C1 which is saved at A2, then I am getting Insufficient previliges Error because the user don't have access to A2.

Please suggest any solution to resolve this.
TIA

Comment: If even a single user should not have access to a record then the owd should be private. Rules are to grant access not restrict them

Comment: In this case, the users belongs to one Account region can see the records in that region only.

Comment: right. Then owd should be private

Comment: Thanks @Eric
and I have a question :
  If I make Account's OWD as Private, can other users able to have Read access on Accounts belong to the same region?

Comment: Suggest you read up on Salesforce security. The golden rule is "OWD is used to restrict not grant access. Sharing is used to grant access" also, if the answer to the question should any single user NOT be able to see a record is true then the OWD should be private. To answer your question, yes, you grant them access by Sharing settings. If you make everything Public read, you CANNOT make the security more strict than that as you cannot take away access with anything except by using OWD.

Comment: Small change in the question(highlighted in the description),
If a user belongs to an account region can able to see(Read access) the account records of another region, then Account must have Public Read only. So I dont want it to be private.

Comment: Absolutely NOT. If ANY user (even 1) should not be able to see ANY (even 1) Account record then OWD MUST BE Private. I cannot be any more clear. Suggest you read up on security and OWD VS Sharing.